# Environment Variables in Fabric2

Tags: python, fabric

I’m using Python 3.6 and Fabric 2.4. I’m using Fabric to SSH into a server and run some commands. I need to set an environment variable for the commands being run on the remote server. The documentation indicates that something like this should work:

```
from fabric import task

@task(hosts=["servername"])
def do_things(c):
    c.run("command_to_execute", env={"KEY": "VALUE"})
```

But that doesn’t work. Something like this should also be possible:

```
from fabric import task

@task(hosts=["servername"])
def do_things(c):
    c.config.run.env = {"KEY": "VALUE"}
    c.run("command_to_execute")
```

But that doesn’t work either. I feel like I’m missing something. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Rob, I wonder if my solution was helpful and helped to you solve your problem!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do it by setting `inline_ssh_env=True`, and then explicitly setting the env variable, ex:

```
with Connection(host=hostname, user=username, inline_ssh_env=True) as c:
    c.config.run.env = {"MY_VAR": "this worked"}
    c.run('echo $MY_VAR')
```

Comment: what fabric version that you use also paramiko and invoke package version

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the site of Fabric:

> The root cause of this is typically because the SSH server runs non-interactive commands via a very limited shell call: /path/to/shell -c "command" (for example, OpenSSH). Most shells, when run this way, are not considered to be either interactive or login shells; and this then impacts which startup files get loaded.

You read more on this page [link](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#the-remote-shell-environment-doesn-t-match-interactive-shells)

So what you try to do won't work, and the solution is to pass the environment variable you want to set explicitly:

```
from fabric import task

    @task(hosts=["servername"])
    def do_things(c):
        c.config.run.env = {"KEY": "VALUE"}
        c.run('echo export %s >> ~/.bashrc ' % 'ENV_VAR=VALUE' )
        c.run('source ~/.bashrc' )
        c.run('echo $ENV_VAR') # to verify if it's set or not! 
        c.run("command_to_execute")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
@task
def qa(ctx):
  ctx.config.run.env['counter'] = 22
  ctx.config.run.env['conn'] = Connection('qa_host')

@task
def sign(ctx):
  print(ctx.config.run.env['counter'])
  conn = ctx.config.run.env['conn']
  conn.run('touch mike_was_here.txt')
```

And run:

```
fab2 qa sign
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating the `Connection` object, try adding `inline_ssh_env=True`.

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.3/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.__init):

> Whether to send environment variables “inline” as prefixes in front of command strings (`export VARNAME=value && mycommand here`), instead of trying to submit them through the SSH protocol itself (which is the default behavior). This is necessary if the remote server has a restricted `AcceptEnv` setting (which is the common default).

Answer (score 0):

According to [that part of the official doc](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.__init__), the `connect_kwargs` attribute of the `Connection` object is intended to replace the `env` dict. I use it, and it works as expected.