# Create alias in fabric2

Tags: python, fabric

So I have pipenv and I want to use it with fabric :

```
c.config.run.env = {"LC_ALL": "en_US.UTF-8", "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8"}

with c.cd('~/Workspace/Micro/productmicro/'):
    c.run("/usr/local/bin/pipenv run python ProductMicro.py &")
```

How to make a proper alias for pipenv ?

Comment: What is the output of your running `cat ~/.bash_profile | grep /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875400/6660766